# only allow external connections by openvpn

Tags: openvpn

I have an openvpn configured and running.

For security reasosns (I often have to connect from hotels WiFi) I need to allow my computer to connect to internet only if the vpn is running.
How do I ensure this? I've tried a lot of things but nothing is working for me.
For example after waking from hibernation, in the time I'm running the openvpn command, my gmail is already connected, skype, etc.

How can redirect all traffic to openvpn and if it's not active don't get an external connection?

Comment: Think iptables is the solution. You can block all non VPN traffic: you find a sample script [HERE](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1973163)
changed it with your interfaces names